# ng-pattern is not working for input type Number in Inline html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i was using this ng-pattern in external html file it was working fine
ng-pattern is

`ng-pattern="/^-?\\d{0,12}(\\.\\d{1,4})?/"`
 now i have included this ng-pattern in inline html means `js+html` now it is not working **input type is number** so is there  any reason behind it ,ng-pattern will not work for input type number in Case of inline html

```
Validation :Total of 16 digits including 4 digits after decimal point are allowed
```

part of html:

```
   <input type="number"  ng-model="ersProfileSectionData[field.code]"   
       ng- pattern="/^-?\\d{0,12}(\\.\\d{1,4})?/"/>'
```

Comment: specify properly with html and javascript code

Comment: Please add example of correct pattern and incorrect pattern

Comment: both are same  pattern  but not working in inline html

Comment: There is space betwee "ng-" and "pattern". Please remove it

Comment: i have fixed it  i have used //// slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANswer is

```
ng- pattern="/^-?\\\\d{0,12}(\\\\.\\\\d{1,4})?/"/>'
```